# Alert message not popped up after using Array.concat method

Tags: javascript

I tried the following code in `IE9, Chrome`. But it is not working in both browsers.

In `Firefox`, it is working fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var first = ['a','b','c','h','i','j'];
    var second = ['d','e','f','g'];
    var insertPosIndex = 3;
    first.splice.apply(first, Array.concat(insertPosIndex, 0, second));
    alert(first);
</script>
```

I am expecting the output as `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j`

Comment: Just tried it in FF works fine. Chrome javascript doesnt have Array.concat() function

Comment: [It works for me on Chromium](http://jsfiddle.net/kdPyX/)

Comment: Yes, It works fine in `Firefox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var first = ['a','b','c','h','i','j'];
    var second = ['d','e','f','g'];
    var insertPosIndex = 3;
    first.splice.apply(first, [].concat(insertPosIndex, 0, second));
    alert(first);
</script>
```

According to a bug, read about it [here](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/710/arrayconcat-doesnt-work-on-chrome-ie) using `[]` instead of `Array` is the work around for Chrome.

This will work in Firefox, IE9 and Chrome.

Comment: Yes, Now I used `[]` instead of `Array` and it is working fine on `IE`, `Firefox` and `Chrome`